# Kafka Spring client with container option AssignmentCommitOption how dose it work?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use Kafka Spring to insert to database processing messages as a batch with container "ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory" and in case of error occurs

1. Bad message I will send that messages to another topic.
2. If connection failed or time out I will rollback both database transaction and producer transaction to prevent false positive

And I don't get assignmentCommitOption option how dose it work and how it different between ALWAYS,NEVER,LATEST_ONLY and LATEST_ONLY_NO_TX,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no current committed offset for a partition that is assigned, this option controls whether or not to commit an initial offset during the assignment.

It is really only useful when using `auto.offset.reset=latest`.

Consider this scenario.

Application comes up and is assigned a "new" partition; the consumer will be positioned at the end of the topic.

No records are received from that topic/partition and the application is stopped.

A record is then published to the topic/partition and the consumer application restarted.

Since there is still no committed offset for the partition, it will again be positioned at the end and we won't receive the published record.

This may be what you want, but it may not be.

Setting the option to `ALWAYS`, `LATEST_ONLY`, or `LATEST_ONLY_NO_TX` (default) will cause the initial position to be committed during assignment so the published record will be received.

The `_NO_TX` variant commits the offset via the `Consumer`, the other one commits it via a transactional producer.